# What does DUPO indicates in MS DOS?

Tags: dos

while sorting in MS DOS, what does DUPO does in below code sample?

```
SORT BLDAPPA.JMP BLDAPPA.J%1 /S(1,13,C,A) DUPO(1,13)
```

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS?  The command line in Windows has nothing to do with "MS-DOS"?

Comment: yes,, this is a part of a program which was written in 90s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MS-DOS `sort` command doesn't support a second filename argument, nor does it support the `/S` option. This command is apparently meant to invoke a third party program that isn't part of MS-DOS (or Windows) that's also unfortunately named `SORT`.

Googling turns up [Opttech Sort](http://www.opttech.com/) which supports a DUPOUT parameter, which can be shortened to DUPO.  This option apparently eliminates duplicate lines keeping only one of them. So `DUPO(1,13)` would eliminate lines whose first 13 bytes are same as another line in the file.